# Find constant K such that the inequality is satisfied

Tags: inequality

Find constant K s.t.

$|tx| + |e^{t^2/2}| \leq K(|x|+1)$

$|tx-ty| \leq K(|x-y|)$

What K works, and how to come up with one? It doesn't look like there is any such K considering there seems to be no upper bound for t, x or y, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, note that

$$|t||x-y|=|tx-ty| \le K |x-y|\underbrace{\iff}_{x\ne y} |t|\le K.$$ That is, the constant $K$ exist if and only if $t$ is bounded. In such a case $|t|\le K$ is the constant that works.

In the first case

$$e^{t^2/2}\le |tx| + e^{t^2/2} \le K(|x|+1)$$ implies that $t$ must be bounded, say $|t|\le T.$ In such a case

$$|tx| + e^{t^2/2}\le T|x|+e^{T^2/2} \le e^{T^2/2}(|x|+1).$$ That is, $K=e^{T^2/2}$ works.

Comment: How do you know all this? Is there a solving special inequalities class I skipped in college?

Comment: The simpler case is the second one. You write the inequality assuming it holds and you get the value of $K.$ There is no any special inequality in this case. Of course, to solve some specific problem the knowledge of inequalities would be useful.

Comment: Wait mfl, I just realized. You conclude t is bounded, but how do you know K exists? Sorry I was unclear. I am trying to show the solution to an SDE is unique. To do so, I have to show that there exists a K s.t. those two inequalities hold.

Comment: Oh I think my notes say stuff that imply t < T. I'll just go with that then. Thanks

Comment: In the second case $t$ is bounded means there exists a constant such that $|t|\le T.$ Just consider $K=T.$

Comment: Yeah but how do you know t is bounded? Anyway I think t is actually bounded by definition. Thanks. Good to know I was sorta right about $e^{t^2/2}$

Comment: If $t$ is not bounded then it is impossible to have $|tx-ty| \le K|x-y|.$ Take $t>K$ and $x\ne y.$ Then, $|tx-ty| > K|x-y|.$

Comment: Yeah I have to show that there exists a K in the first place. You said t is bounded iff K exists. So if t isn't bounded, then K doesn't exist. That's that. There's nothing that says K exists. Sorry for the confusion. I'm sticking with what you posted and what I came up with (revised from t to T). Again, thanks